# Reactjs routes, link over params

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with routes:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/dodajpost" component={addPost} />
      <Route path="/:id" component={App}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

And when I'm going to `/dodajpost` it doesn't render the `addPost` component, the `/:id` is over the `/dodajpost`.

Is it possible to give a higher priority to the `/dodajpost`? Or maybe there is different way to fix it.

Comment: you can use `<Switch> routes here</Switch>` probably but I don't actually understand the role of the third `Route`

Comment: According to the code the app should be rendering `addPost` and `App` and the `addPost` should be getting  the string `dodajpost` as the value of `id` router param. If you don't see `addPost` it could be `App` is covering it. 
If you want to render one or the other you need use `<Switch>` like @EdwardChopuryan suggested.

Comment: did you tried add exact in the third route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to do as below :

- First, use the `<Switch>`, it is not required for grouping `<Route>`  but it can be quite useful when multiple route’s paths match the same pathname.
- About the priority, the `<Switch>` only render the first one that matches the current location
- Check if your current location matches exactly the `'/dodajpost'`
- Instead of `addPost` use `AddPost`, it's a convention in react that the components start with the capital letter

Do like this and try again !

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, the <switch> is working exactly as i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
   ReactDOM.render((
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" component={App} />
          <Route exact path="/dodajpost" component={addPost} />
          <Route exact path="/:id" component={App}/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```